# How to make the textblock text centered in a button with image and text if no image is available in WPF

Tags: xaml, imagebutton

I have a button with the image and textblock.
Buttons are created dynamically based on the values from the database.
Now for a particular value text is present and no image is there I want to show that text in the center of the button (horizontally and vertically), but it is not working.

Please find the xaml below:

```
<ItemsControl ItemsSource="{Binding CategoriesList}">
    <ItemsControl.ItemTemplate>
        <DataTemplate>
            <Button Width="100" Margin="5" HorizontalContentAlignment="Center" VerticalContentAlignment="Center">
                <Button.Template>
                    <ControlTemplate>
                        <Border CornerRadius="10" Background="Maroon">
                            <StackPanel Orientation="Vertical">
                                <Image Source="{Binding CategoryImagePath}" Height="50"></Image>
                                <TextBlock Text="{Binding CategoryName}" Height="20" HorizontalAlignment="Center" VerticalAlignment="Center"></TextBlock>
                            </StackPanel>
                        </Border>
                    </ControlTemplate>
                </Button.Template>
            </Button>
        </DataTemplate>
    </ItemsControl.ItemTemplate>
    <ItemsControl.ItemsPanel>
        <ItemsPanelTemplate>
            <WrapPanel/>
        </ItemsPanelTemplate>
    </ItemsControl.ItemsPanel>
</ItemsControl>
```

If no image is available I want to show only the text on the button but it should be centered.

If there is Image then I make the Image and text both displayed but when the Image is not available the text is getting displayed but it is not in the center It moves to the top portion of the button.

Answer (score 1):

You can use a `DataTemplateSelector` to select different templates depending on whether you have an image. Such a selector might look like this:

```
public sealed class ButtonTemplateSelector : DataTemplateSelector
{
    /// <summary>
    /// Gets or sets the <see cref="DataTemplate"/> to use when we have an image.
    /// The value is set in XAML.
    /// </summary>
    public DataTemplate ImageTemplate { get; set; }

    /// <summary>
    /// Gets or sets the <see cref="DataTemplate"/> to use when we don't have an image.
    /// The value is set in XAML.
    /// </summary>
    public DataTemplate NoImageTemplate { get; set; }

    public override DataTemplate SelectTemplate(object item, DependencyObject container)
    {
        Category category = item as Category;
        if (category != null)
        {
            return category.CategoryImagePath == null ? NoImageTemplate : ImageTemplate;
        }

        return base.SelectTemplate(item, container);
    }
}
```

I'm assuming a model object something like this:

```
public class Category
{
    public string CategoryImagePath { get; set; }

    public string CategoryName { get; set; }
}
```

Create and initialize a `ButtonTemplateSelector` resource in your XAML, then reference it from your `ItemsControl`:

```
<Window
    x:Class="WPF.MainWindow"
    x:Name="self"
    xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml/presentation"
    xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml"
    xmlns:d="http://schemas.microsoft.com/expression/blend/2008"
    xmlns:mc="http://schemas.openxmlformats.org/markup-compatibility/2006"
    xmlns:wpf="clr-namespace:WPF"
    mc:Ignorable="d"
    Title="MainWindow"
    Height="350"
    Width="525">
    <Grid>
        <Grid.Resources>
            <wpf:ButtonTemplateSelector x:Key="ButtonTemplateSelector">
                <wpf:ButtonTemplateSelector.ImageTemplate>
                    <DataTemplate DataType="wpf:Category">
                        <Button
                            Width="100"
                            Margin="5"
                            HorizontalContentAlignment="Center"
                            VerticalContentAlignment="Center">
                            <Button.Template>
                                <ControlTemplate>
                                    <Border CornerRadius="10" Background="Maroon">
                                        <StackPanel Orientation="Vertical">
                                            <Image
                                                Source="{Binding CategoryImagePath}"
                                                Height="50" />
                                            <TextBlock
                                                Foreground="White"
                                                Text="{Binding CategoryName}"
                                                Height="20"
                                                HorizontalAlignment="Center"
                                                VerticalAlignment="Center" />
                                        </StackPanel>
                                    </Border>
                                </ControlTemplate>
                            </Button.Template>
                        </Button>
                    </DataTemplate>
                </wpf:ButtonTemplateSelector.ImageTemplate>
                <wpf:ButtonTemplateSelector.NoImageTemplate>
                    <DataTemplate DataType="wpf:Category">
                        <Button
                            Width="100"
                            Margin="5"
                            HorizontalContentAlignment="Center"
                            VerticalContentAlignment="Center">
                            <Button.Template>
                                <ControlTemplate>
                                    <Border
                                        CornerRadius="10"
                                        Background="Maroon"
                                        Height="70">
                                        <TextBlock
                                            Foreground="White"
                                            Text="{Binding CategoryName}"
                                            Height="20"
                                            HorizontalAlignment="Center"
                                            VerticalAlignment="Center" />
                                    </Border>
                                </ControlTemplate>
                            </Button.Template>
                        </Button>
                    </DataTemplate>
                </wpf:ButtonTemplateSelector.NoImageTemplate>
            </wpf:ButtonTemplateSelector>
        </Grid.Resources>
        <ItemsControl
            DataContext="{Binding ElementName=self}"
            ItemsSource="{Binding CategoriesList}"
            ItemTemplateSelector="{StaticResource ButtonTemplateSelector}">
            <ItemsControl.ItemsPanel>
                <ItemsPanelTemplate>
                    <WrapPanel/>
                </ItemsPanelTemplate>
            </ItemsControl.ItemsPanel>
        </ItemsControl>
    </Grid>
</Window>
```

For completeness, the code-behind for the window:

```
public partial class MainWindow
{
    public MainWindow()
    {
        InitializeComponent();
    }

    public IEnumerable<Category> CategoriesList { get; } = new List<Category>
        {
            new Category { CategoryName = "First", CategoryImagePath = "/Assets/Square.bmp" },
            new Category { CategoryName = "Second", CategoryImagePath = null },
        };
}
```

This shows up as follows, which I think is what you're asking:

[image: My image is a red square]

Comment: There are other options -- for example, you hardcoded the image height. If you hardcoded the button height instead, the image part might collapse into nothingness, and you'd be left with a vertically centered string. Depends on your data, though...

Comment: Thanks for the answer Peter. You understood what I wanted but I have few questions if you could help me out.

Comment: Sure, I'll give it a go. (If you like the answer, consider accepting it.)

Comment: Do I need to set the datacontext fo the ItemsControl even if I am setting the datacontext for the user control in which we have this items control tag.                                                                                                               2) After doing the required changes also the text does not get centered. is there any way I can debug the xaml as the templateselector code is working as expected when I debugged that.

Comment: You don't have to set the `DataContext` of the `ItemsControl` explicitly; if it's `null` it will just walk up the hierarchy. I just had to set it _somewher_ to get a running sample -- setting it on the `Grid` or the `Window` works just as well.

Comment: Not sure I understand your second question; as far as I can tell the text _is_ centered...?